# How to check if value contains a specific letter and update the value accordingly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, handlebars.js

In MVC c# solution i am using something like below in .cshtml file,  how can I check if the url contains a '?'. 
If yes then i want this url value to pass to a .cs file a where a method is written to update the url and then will use it in the view.

In the cshtml it is `{{ImageUrl}}?w=300`, but sometime the url comes with a `?` append at the end like `test.png?la=en`. If already a `?` mark is there i want `&w=900` instead of `?w=300`. the url should be `test.png?la=en&w=300`
instead of `test.png?la=en?w=900`

Sample HTML:

```html
<div data-picture="{{ImageUrl}}" data-alt="{{Alt}}" data-title="{{Title}}" data-class="img-responsive">
<div data-src="{{ImageUrl}}?w=300"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: To give us a bit of a context, could you explain what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: What is the expected input? What does the output would look like? and the most important thing, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Include your code snippet for better clarity

Comment: The cshtml it is {{URL}}?w=900, but sometime the url come with a '?' append at the end like 'test.png?la=en'. If already a ? mark is there i want &w=900 instead of ?w=900. the url should be test.png?la=en&w=900 instead of test.png?la=en?w=900

Comment: Edit your post with a correct description of your problem, don't put it in comments thanks. :)

Comment: @Debaparna Please update your question with relevant information and not in the comments.